# Rails Activerecord where date from 20 to 20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have to display only the works between the 20th of one month to the 20th of next month (each period from 20 to 20 of every month)

I see two cases:

1.- If I`m at 15 of any month(or lower than 20) I have to display from 20 of last month to today.

2.- If I´m at 25 of any month(or higher than 20) I Have to display from 20 of this month to today.

I don't know the syntax for that
Something like this

```
if Date.today.day > 20
  @works = Work.where(created_at: "20 of this month to Date.today")
else
  @works = Work.where(created_at: "20 of last month to Date.today")
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all, I took your ideas and this work for me

```
if Date.today.day > 20
  @works = Work.where(created_at: ((Date.new((Date.today.year),(Date.today.month),21)))..Date.today)
else
  @works = Work.where(created_at: ((Date.new((Date.today.year),(Date.today.month),21)) - 1.month)..Date.today)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date = Date.today.change(day: 20)
date -= 1.month if date > Date.today
@works = Work.where(created_at: date..(date + 1.month))
```

Depending on your specific requirements, the last condition could be any  of the following:

```
date..(date + 1.month)
date...(date + 1.month)
date..date.today
date...date.today
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I did once (this is written from memory, not tested)

```
if Date.today.day > 20
  start_day = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 20)
  end_day   = start_day + 1.month
else
  start_day = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 20) - 1.month
  end_day   = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 20)
end

Work.where(created_at: start_day..end_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
# The ".." sets a range, (from)..(to)
if Date.today.day > 20
  @works = Work.where(created_at: (Date.today - 20)..(Date.today))
else
  @works = Work.where(created_at: (Date.today.change(day: 20))..(Date.today))
end
```

You may also want to check the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html) for additional DateTime calculations :)